# Prompting message to user to Save the current row on DavaGridView_RowLeave

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview, architecture

I have two DataGridViews with editable by the user.
When the user select a row in DataGridViewA then DatagridViewB is populated with different data accordingly.

Once edited the current row in DataGridViewA, the user can click on the save button. In case he didn't save and select another row in DataGridViewA, a message for save will be prompted to the user asking him if he want to save before moving to another row. (I have a method that check if there are changes and if yes, prompt a message to the user if he wants to save - yes: Save, No: Restore Data).

The method that checks if there are changes is triggered on DataGridViewA_Leave(). The reason is that I have the information of the DataGridViewA.CurrentRow before leaving the row so I can Save if needed.

The problem is if I am clicking on any other control on my form such as Save button the Save message to the user prompt (because the DataGridViewA.CurrentRow is left). In this case, I do not want the user to get a message.

I found a workaround to fix it but it is not the best way to do it I presume. Before prompting the message, I am checking if the Save button has focus. This check need to be done for all the controls that I don't want to get a Save message when clicking on them.

Is there any better solution to solve this issue?

My code, the record state is Added (user add a row) or Edited (user update some data) :

```
private void AlternateDGV_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (IsSaveNeeded)
        {
            if (SaveButton.Focused) // This is the work around
            {
                return;
            }

            if (!WasSavedPerUserRequest())
            {
                var recordstate = AlternateDGV.CurrentRow.Cells[Glossary.RecordStateName].Value.ToString();
                if (recordstate == Glossary.AddedRecordState)   // if it was a new row added and the user doesn't want to save
                {                        
                    AlternateDGV.CurrentRow.Delete();
                }
                else if (recordstate == Glossary.EditedRecordState) // if it was a row from DB and the user doesn't want to save, refresh with saved data
                {
                    AlternateDGV.CurrentRow.Refresh(_items);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: DataGridView.LostFocus?

Comment: What do you mean by DataGridView.LostFocus?

Comment: Have you considered using the LostFocus event?

Comment: How it can help? Can you please explain?

Comment: You could use it the same way as RowLeave - perhaps it would be more complicated...I think your 'workaround' is a pretty simple solution - stick with it :)

Comment: Why don't you use SelectionChanged event instead of Leave? You could save the current selected row in a local variable and when the selection changes you prompt the message to the user and if necessary you save the configuration. Am I missing something?

Comment: It a matter of saving all the information of the current row in DataGridViewA and also all the information from DatagridViewB which could contain a lot of records. It looks like a duplication of data. I prefered to find another solution without having to manage an additional cache for it.

Comment: I don't think so. When do you load new data into DataGridViewB? If you're loading data when selection changes, you can first check the configuration before deleting previously loaded rows in DataGridVeiwB, so you don't need a cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you should change something in the method you use to load data and manage the grid.

If you load the data in DataGridViewB using the DataGridViewA.SelectionChanged event, you should be able to check for unsaved changes and then reload the DataGridViewB content.

**NOTE:** SelectionChanged event is fired only after the selected row is changed, so you should at least save the index of the current selected row when loading the rows in DataGridViewB, so you can check the correct row when a new row is selected.

For example:

```
void DataGridViewA_SelectionChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (previousSelectedIndex != -1)
   {
      //Check for changes end if necessary prompt the message
      [...]
   }

   //Load data in DataGridViewB
   [...]

   previousSelectedIndex = dataGridViewA.SelectedRows[0].Index;
}
```

EDIT:

Another solution could be to check if the grid still has the focus. If it has not, then the user clicked outside the grid and you don't have to prompt the message.

```
private void DataGridViewA_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (IsSaveNeeded)
        {
            if (dataGridViewA.Focused == false)
            {   //DataGridViewA without focus, then nothing to do
                return;
            }

            if (!WasSavedPerUserRequest())
            {
                var recordstate = AlternateDGV.CurrentRow.Cells[Glossary.RecordStateName].Value.ToString();
                if (recordstate == Glossary.AddedRecordState)   // if it was a new row added and the user doesn't want to save
                {                        
                    AlternateDGV.CurrentRow.Delete();
                }
                else if (recordstate == Glossary.EditedRecordState) // if it was a row from DB and the user doesn't want to save, refresh with saved data
                {
                    AlternateDGV.CurrentRow.Refresh(_items);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I really understand what you mean but I think it may have a solution using the events. So many events and a such simple thing should be solved accordingly without having to manage the data in addition to the DataGridView itself. Thank you

Comment: I understand what you're looking for, but I thing you should focus on selection changing, because making assumption on where the user is clicking is the wrong way to manage the problem. Consider that the user could also change selection by using arrow keys, eventually, when the focus is on DataGridViewA. What is your desired effect in that case?

Comment: in this case row_enter is raised and that's fine to me.

Comment: Ok, I added a possible different solution, maybe you've already tried it.

Comment: It is very similar to the workaround I wrote in my post. What will happen in case that the user click on the save button? The focus will move to the button and not to the grid itself.

Comment: Exactly, so the message will not prompt to the user. The same thing will happen if the user click anywhere outside the grid, so I think that this is what you're looking for, am I wrong? It's similar to your workaround, but it supports also the click on other controls in your form.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you make visible 'Save' button once User click on Edit button at row level , So when user click on edit button and suddenly leave the row you can check visibility of save button at row level on your AlternateDGV_RowLeave event if it is still visible that means that user has not clicked the save button yet and you can prompt user.

Comment: I presume you meant enable/disabled button (not visible). I am not doing so and it will not help since if the user leave the row to click the save button I don't want to prompt but if he leave the row to select another row then I want to prompt.